# Matrix Field Integration

Tags: matrix

I'm just looking for a little guidance here. I have a decent grasp of the matrix field but the functionality I want exactly is causing me some issues.

Im trying to setup a matrix field with the following:

```
Category name: Football (need the ability to set the category is in panel)

 -> PDFs 

  -> PDF Title (Title of PDF)
  -> PDF Asset (Upload PDF Here)

  -> PDF Title (Title of PDF)
  -> PDF Asset (Upload PDF Here)


Category name: Rugby (need the ability to set the category is in panel)

 -> PDFs 

  -> PDF Title (Title of PDF)
  -> PDF Asset (Upload PDF Here)

  -> PDF Title (Title of PDF)
  -> PDF Asset (Upload PDF Here)



  etc.
```

So looking at the matrix field it look like I need someway to create a matrix field within a matrixfield? I see i can use some plugins for this, But i want to make sure im not missing something first.

Thank you very much.

### UPDATE

I've setup my matrix field like this, is this correct for what I want?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Matrix field inside a matrix field I recommend using Supertables.

https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable

It doesn't look exactly the same as a matrix block but works the exact same way. With supertables you can go as deep as you want.
Super table is a field you can add into your matrix block which is able to use all the fields you want so you dont have any limitations.

My first impression on your Matrix field looks alright to me but, I might misunderstand it.